# Formatting rows (color, line-through etc.) based on date in Google Sheets with script

Tags: google-apps-script, formatting, google-sheets

I've made a list of events in Google Sheets to help me and my band to get an overview of when we are to play. We have had a lot of jobs lately, and it is getting a little hard to quickly figure out where the next job is...

If it's possible, I would like to automatically make the rows containing previous jobs in italics, line-through and the font-color gray if the dates i column C is before the today/current date.

I have been searching a lot for it, but haven't really quite found the right piece of code..
My skills in scripting is OK, but this is the first time for me to use Google apps script, so I would appreciate if you could explain some of the harder steps about the more Google Sheets specific parts of the code :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a script to do that : in your spreadsheet, format>conditional formating.
[image]

---

### EDIT :

Since you seem to prefer using a script to customize it more personally (which I understand ;-)
here is a script to begin with : (it does not need a lot of explanations, see comments in code)

```
function formatOnDate() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sh.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var color = '#CCC';// value you want
  var style = 'italic';// value you want
  var line = 'line-through';// value you want
  var fontColors = range.getFontColors();// get all font colors
  var fontLines = range.getFontLines();// lines
  var fontStyles = range.getFontStyles();//style
  //var today = new Date();// include today in sheet
  var today = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1));// exclude today... uncomment the one you use
  for(var n=1 ; n<data.length ; n++){ // start on row 2 so that headers are not changed
    if(data[n][2] < today){
      for(var c in data[0]){
        fontColors[n][c]=color;//set format
        fontLines[n][c]=line;//set format
        fontStyles[n][c]=style;//set format
      }
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).clear();
  // now update sheet with new data and style
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data).setFontColors(fontColors).setFontLines(fontLines).setFontStyles(fontStyles);
}
```

Test [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qcLCU9APBEXabWidLNt2l8SxEmzsQblIyvxdxyoOV9E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The jobs are in rows, and for every row there is a date (in column C). If that date is before today I want to format the whole row :)
Does that make sense, I don't believe you can do that with conditional formatting.. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, it is possible to conditionally format (without script) entire rows based on the date in one column. However, you can only format font colour and cell background colour in this way (not font styling formats like italics and strike-through).